# similar to "seemore" functionality in facebook

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, kendo-ui

I am using asp.net MVC3.

I have a paragraph with 30 lines of data.
Initially I have to display first two lines of data .
I have a button name "Full Details",when I click on this,I have to display total 30 lines of data.

how can I implement this

Comment: What have you done till now..? Could you share the HTML layout.. Do you plan to implement this in pure JS and no plans to use JQuery in the future?

Comment: actually I am using kendoUI framework.I didn't get any idea how to implement this and I don't have plans to use jquery

Comment: Unrelated note: intersting statement "don't have plans to use jQuery" when using "jQuery-powered... Kendo UI"

Comment: Ok, seems like kendo packages JQuery. I would suggest you retag this question to JQuery for a cleaner solution.

Comment: Yup Kendo requires JQuery 1.8.2 or higher.. [See this.](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/javascript-dependencies). So JQuery is the  way to go...

Comment: Have you looked at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752891/expanding-paragraph-html-for-news-section (Implemented using JS though...)